# iOS - Remove vertical space between UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` that has three cells on each row. There is no vertical space between the cells on all iPhones, except iPhone SE.

There is like 1 point vertical space between the second and the last cells on iPhone SE. I do not understand where it comes from. How to get rid of it?

[image]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let collection = ColorCollectionView(sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds: false)
        self.view.addSubview(collection)
        collection.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        collection.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        collection.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive  = true
        collection.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -8).isActive  = true
        collection.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let colors: [UIColor] = [.systemGray, .systemGray2, .systemGray3,
                                 .systemGray, .systemGray2, .systemGray3,
                                 .systemGray, .systemGray2, .systemGray3,
                                 .systemGray, .systemGray2, .systemGray3,
                                 .systemGray, .systemGray2, .systemGray3,
                                 .systemGray, .systemGray2, .systemGray3,
                                 .systemGray, .systemGray2, .systemGray3,
                                 .systemGray, .systemGray2, .systemGray3,
                                 .systemGray, .systemGray2, .systemGray3,
                                 .systemGray, .systemGray2, .systemGray3,
                                 .systemGray, .systemGray2, .systemGray3,
                                 .systemGray, .systemGray2, .systemGray3,]
        collection.colors = colors
    }
}



class ColorCollectionView: UICollectionView {
    var colors: [UIColor] = []
    
    var selectedColor: UIColor?
    
    var headerName: String?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect, collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {
        super.init(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.register(ColorCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier:ColorCollectionViewCell.identifier)
        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self
    }
    
    convenience init(sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds: Bool) {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        self.init(frame: .zero,  collectionViewLayout: layout)
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}



extension ColorCollectionView: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width / 3, height: 60)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 8
    }
}



extension ColorCollectionView: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return colors.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: ColorCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath)
        let color = colors[indexPath.row]
        cell.backgroundColor = color
        return cell
    }
}

class ColorCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static let identifier = "ColorCollectionViewCell"
}
```

I have included all of  my code.

### Update

View's width: is **375.0**

CollectionView's width: **359.0**

CollectionVeiwCell's widht: **119.66666666666667**

Comment: Are you testing on simulator or real device ?

Comment: @CZ54 I have tested both on simulator real device.

Comment: `CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width / 3, height: 60)` what's the value of that? I guess it's a "half pixel line" ("half", being "third" or "two thirds" in your case).

Answer (score 0):

You should try to set the **interCellSpacing** to the following:

```
self.tableView setIntercellSpacing:NSMakeSize(0, 0)];
```

See the apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/1524258-intercellspacing).

> Table views normally have a 1 pixel separation between consecutively selected rows or columns.

Setting an intercell spacing of (0,0) should remove the separation between your cells.

Also check the drawing code of your cells. The gap you see could be the border of your cell subclass. You could override the **drawRect(rect:)** method and set the border width and border color there to see if a border is the problem. So in your cell subclass:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    }
```

Hope it helps!

---

Edit:

Instead of using the **delegate** methods directly you could try to assign it directly (I tried it myself and it is working for me)

```
 if let collectionViewFlowLayout = collection.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout{
            // the width of your main view or your parent view
            let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
            // what ever item size you need
            collectionViewFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width / 2, height: width / 2)

            // probably you need also to set the section inset
            collectionViewFlowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
        layout
            
            collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
            collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
            
            // assign your collection view layout to your collectionViewFlowLayout
            yourCollectionView.collectionViewFlowLayout = collectionViewFlowLayout
        }
```

Comment: Does UICollectionView have setIntercellSpacing?

Comment: Could be the case. I am actually not quite sure at the moment. I know that its working for **UITableView**. I updated my answer.